# Округление в большую сторону

Tags: java, математика, числа, округление

Откуда взялась формула `(a + b - 1) / b` для округления дроби в большую сторону?
Где можно прочитать про ее вывод?

Comment: А почему вы называете это округлением? Кажется тут чего-то не хватает. Например собственно округления (избавления от дробной части).

Comment: @AlexeyTen, в C-подобных языках оператор деления на значениях целого типа сам производит округление к целому. Надо к вопросу добавить какой-то тег связанный с программированием вообще. Не нашёл такого. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

при обычном делении получаем округление в меньшую

```
6 / 7 = 0
7 / 7 = 1
8 / 7 = 1
```

а вы хотите в большую. Добавляем делитель

```
(6 + 7) / 7 = 1
(7 + 7) / 7 = 2
(8 + 7) / 7 = 2
```

Чуть чуть не так, хочется `7 / 7 = 1` , тогда отнимаем единицу

```
(6 + 7 - 1) / 7 = 1
(7 + 7 - 1) / 7 = 1
(8 + 7 - 1) / 7 = 2
```

Вот и получилась формула методом тыка `(число + делитель - 1) / делитель`

Answer (score 11):

Ну а что тут читать? естественно, предполагается, что `a` и `b` - натуральные, так?

Тогда при `a` в диапазоне от `kb+1` до `kb+b` мы должны получить в качестве "окргуления" :) в большую сторону значение `k+1`. Так?

Например, от 11 до 15 при делении на 5 мы должны получить 3.

В нашем распоряжении есть целочисленное деление, отбрасывающее дробную часть. Чтобы получить с его помощью значение `k+1` для `a = kb+1`, мы должны прибавить к нему по крайней мере `b-1`, и получить `kb+b`, которое при делении на `b` даст ровно `k+1`, без остатка.

Если мы это же значение прибавим к следующему по величине числу, получится тот же результат деления, так как остаток `1/b` будет отброшен. И так - до значения `kb+b`, при котором деление отбросит остаток `(b-1)/b`, меньший `1`.

Вот собственно и все. Получается, что прибавление `b-1` обеспечивает округление `a/b` в большую сторону за счет появления остатка, меньшего `1`, при целочисленном делении.

**Разжевывание 1**

Любое число `a` можно представить как `kb+c`, где `k` — результат целочисленного деления `a` на `b`, а `c` —  остаток от деления.

Например, `a = 12`, `b = 5`, итого `k = 2`, `c = 2`. Вы хотите с округлением в большую сторону получать как результат не 2, а 3.

При делении `kb` на `b` получается *ровно* `k`, так что округление в большую сторону дает тот же результат. А вот для чисел от `kb+1` до `kb+b-1`получающийся результат целочисленного деления `k` нужно для округления в большую сторону увеличить на 1. Т.е. по сути прибавить `b/b`...

**Разжевывание 2**

По сути нужно прибавить к результату 1, т.е. `b/b`, т.е. вроде бы `a/b+b/b = (a+b)/b`, но этот результат будет неверен для `a = kb`, так что знаменатель надо чуточку уменьшить - до `(a+b-1)/b`. Тогда для `a = kb` получим `k` (как и надо), а для всех больших `kb`, но меньших `(k+1)b` — `k+1`, как и требовалось.

**Отступление**

По сути, нужно получить функцию "потолок" из функции "пол" для дроби (см. об этих функциях [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)).

Comment: Не понял с самого начала. Почему a в диапазоне от kb+1 до kb+b? Почему мы должны получить k+1? Что такое k вообще? :(

Comment: @moxeeeem А вы разделите оба этих выражения нацело на `b` )  и не важно нему равно `k`, чему-то

Comment: ```k``` - целая часть частного от деления ```a``` на ```b```

Comment: `k` - результат _целочисленного_ деления `a/b`, `k + 1` - округленный в большую сторону.  При целочисленном делении остатки от 1 до `b - 1` отбрасываются, например, для `b = 5` `k = 0, остатки в диапазоне [1; 4] отброшены;  k = 1, a in [6, 9]; k = 2, a in [11, 14]` и т.д.  Отсюда и получен диапазон чисел `a` `[kb + 1, kb + b]`, результат целочисленного деления для которого будет округлен в большую сторону.

Comment: Немного доразжевал в ответе.